# How to make the QLabel background semi-transparent?

Tags: qt

I have created `QLabel *msgLbl`. How do I make the `msgLbl` background semi-transparent?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to call [`setStylesheet()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop). If you're using Qt Designer you can also set the stylesheet from within the designer window (look in the properties bar on the right.

You want to set the `background-color` attribute, so something like

`msgLbl->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);");`

would be the simplest way to do what you describe.

Having said that, you might also want to think about stylesheet inheritance. For example, you might want to set the `background-color` for a number of `QLabel`s, all children of a parent widget. You can do that using css-style selectors in a stylesheet set on the parent widget (read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) for more information).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But i want to make the background semi-transparent.

Comment: The code above should do that: notice you're setting the `background-colour` using rgba. The a stands for alpha, meaning transparency. An alpha setting of 255 is completely opaque, and an alpha of 0 is completely transparent, so `rgba(255, 255, 255, 10)` is a very transparent white.

Comment: Thanks! Now i changed to 'background-color:rgba(182,159,64,230)' and working fine!!

Comment: @Shyam If that answer was helpful to you, you can vote it up, and/or accept it. See [that part of the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for details.

Comment: @sjwarner Even when I use `(255, 255, 255, 0)` I can still see the label box contrasted against my background image... How to solve this?

Comment: @the_prole: This is a pretty old question now. Best to detail the environment and code to reproduce *your* problem in a new question I think.

Comment: @the_prole You need to specify the color of your border and include alpha there, for example `border: 1ex solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)` for a half-transparent red line.