# Overlay a QLabel with a transparent layer

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for the easy way to overlay a `QLabel` that displays an image with a transparent color, say `QColor(0, 0, 0, 220)`.

here is the code of the QLabel subclass i've made:

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget* parent): QLabel(parent){

}


void MyLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* _event)
{
    QPainter p;
    p.begin(this);

    // bugs here: "Recursive repaint detected"
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, width(), height(), this->grab() );  <--

    p.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 220)));
    p.drawRect(0, 0, width(), height());
    p.end();

    QWidget::paintEvent(_event);
}
```

is it necessary to subclass `QLabel` to do this stuff ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928519/how-to-make-the-qlabel-background-semi-transparent <- does that work for you?

Comment: `QWidget::paintEvent(_event)` is wrong. You must call the paint event of the base class (`QLabel`), or nothing at all.