# How to set Transparency for Child QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, transparency

I am using following code to set the transparency for child widget but the output is showing as full white.

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
```

I set the opacity but nothing happen to `QWidget`. How to set transparency to child `QWidget`?

Comment: Are you working in Linux? If so, you need to have a composite manager running. More info in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) and [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18072-How-to-set-Qt-window-transparent).

Comment: [More](https://forum.qt.io/topic/1090/solved-how-to-get-an-simple-transparent-window) info. Maybe a solution for you.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928519/how-to-make-the-qlabel-background-semi-transparent